# Use Scanner to Find Three Numbers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want my scanner to read a `.txt` file and find three integers `int1 int2 int3` and use them as a color code. The only problem is, I don't know how to do that.

So far, I have:

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource")

Scanner[] properties = new Scanner[str];
Color[] colour = new Color[str];

int posx = 200;
int posy = 100;

for (int i = 0; i < str; i++){
    properties[i] = new Scanner(new File("Particles/" + string[i] + ".txt"));
    g.drawString("Particles/" + string[i] + ".txt", 200, posy);
    colour[i] = new Color(properties[i].nextInt(), properties[i].nextInt(),properties[i].nextInt());
    posy = posy + 100;
}
```

(It is only part of a method, that's why `str` ect. isn't declared).

And the file I'm reading from looks like:

```
Name:   Fire
Color:  255 0 0
Speed:  0
Size:   1
```

How do i get it to read the `255 0 0` and use it as a colour?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Just a note - when I think of consecutive integers, I think of `...integers that follow each other in order. They have a difference of 1 between every two numbers. (Wikipedia).` So, you're not looking for consecutive integers - just a set of three numbers.

Comment: Will the word "color" always be present before the RGB values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Scanner` to look for the keyword, and then use that to indicate where/how you want to continue processing.

```
String r, g, b;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(myFile);
while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
    if(next.equals("Color:")) {
        r = scanner.next();
        g = scanner.next();
        b = scanner.next();
        // do stuff with the values
    }
 }
```

To make the values into [Colors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html):

```
Color color = new Color(Integer.parseInt(r), Integer.parseInt(g), Integer.parseInt(b));
```

Alternatively, you could use the [nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28int%29) method in the `Scanner` API to retrieve the numbers directly as `int`s, but I would take them in as `String`s in order to perform further error handling where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this...

```
// lose the Name: line
scanner[i].nextLine()

// lose the Color: label
scanner[i].next()

// get the ints
int c1 = scanner[i].nextInt();
int c2 = scanner[i].nextInt();
int c3 = scanner[i].nextInt();

colour[i] = makeColor(c1, c2, c3);
```

If not, you'll need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could either have the Scanner use the `.nextInt()` method three times when it comes to that specific line, or you could write a method to retrieve the whole line from the text file using the Scanner method `.nextLine()` and have a conditional statement to check if that line contains `Color:` and then parse the integers from the rest of the String.
 Jeff's answer will best suit your needs.